# Relation between stalks of twisted sheaf and structure sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, graded-rings, projective-schemes

> Let $A$ be a ring, $B = A[T_0,\dots, T_d]$, and $X = \textrm{Proj } B$. Then at every point $x \in X$,
>   $$\mathcal{O}_X (n)_x \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$$

Let $x$ correspond to a homogeneous prime ideal $p$.

So by definition, $\mathcal{O}_X(n) = B(n)^\tilde{}$ thus taking stalks, we get $(\tilde{B(n)})_p = B(n)_{(p)}$. The latter is represented by $a/s$ where $a$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n + \deg (s)$.

On the other hand, $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = B_{(p)}$ which is represented by quotients of homogeneous polynomials that are of the same degree.

1. How does one see that these are isomorphic? Should we take a degree $0$ quotient and multiply by $x_0 \dots x_d$ until it is of degree $n$?
2. How general is this result? Does it hold for all such $X$? Does it hold for general twisted sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, let $R$ be a graded ring and let $\operatorname{Proj}R=X$, we can define
\begin{equation}
\forall n\in\mathbb{Z},\,\mathcal{O}_X(n)=\widetilde{R(n)}
\end{equation}
where for any homogeneous element $f\in R$ of degree $m$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}_X(n)_{|D_+(f)}=R_{(f)}(n)=R_{f,0}(n)=\left\{\frac{x}{f^k}\in R_f\mid x\in R_{km}\right\}(n)=\left\{\frac{x}{f^k}\in R_f\mid x\in R_{km+n}\right\};
\end{equation}
then:
\begin{equation}
\forall\mathfrak{p}\in X,\,\left(\mathcal{O}_X(n)\right)_{\mathfrak{p}}=\lim_{\overrightarrow{f\notin\mathfrak{p}}}\mathcal{O}_X(n)_{|D_+(f)}=\dots=R_{\mathfrak{p},0}(n)\simeq R_{\mathfrak{p},0}=\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{p}},
\end{equation}
where an isomorphism of rings is:
\begin{equation}
\varphi_a:\frac{x}{f^k}\in R_{\mathfrak{p},0}(n)\to\frac{x}{f^ka^n}\in R_{\mathfrak{p},0}
\end{equation}
where $a\in R_{\mathfrak{p},1}$.

**Very important remark:** $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ are isomorphic as *quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on $X$ associated to the ring $R$*, but they are not isomorphic as *quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules on $X$ associated to the graded ring $R$*!

Are you agree? Is it all clear?

Comment: what is a «graded $\mathcal O_X$-module»?

Comment: Sorry, I had wrong the terminology; now I hope that it is all correct!

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but with the morphism $\varphi$ described above don't you have $\deg(x)-(k+n)\deg(f)=n(1-\deg(f))$

Comment: @Abellan Yes, you have right! ;) Indeed $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of rings and not an isomorphism of _graded_ rings. :D

Comment: I may still not have understood, but it seems to me that Abellan's comment points to an error, as $x/f^{k+n}$ is not in $R_{\mathfrak{p},0}$. It could be corrected by taking an homogeneous element $a$ of degree 1 not in $\mathfrak{p}$ and sending $x/f^k$ to $x/(f^ka^n)$ instead. Such an $a$ does exist in polynomial rings, however it may not in general (or could it ?).

Comment: @Segipp You are right and very clear! I apologize for my mistake.