# Description of $\mathcal{O}_x(n)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we define the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ to be $S(n)^{\sim} $ where $X = \operatorname{Proj} S$ and $S$ is a graded ring.

$S(n)$ is defined by shifting $n$-places to the left. For example, in the case that $S$ is a polynomial ring the constant terms, $S_0$ would now become terms of degree $n$.

I have seen a heuristic explanation of $\mathcal{O}_x(n)$ as allowing functions on $X$ which have poles of degree $n$. As in the case when $S$ is a polynomial ring.

We define the usual structure sheaf on $\mathcal{O}_x = S^{\sim}$

For each $U \subset X$, we define $S^{\sim}$ to be the set of of functions 
$$ s: U \to \bigsqcup_{\frak{p} \in U} S_{(p)} $$

where $S_{(p)}$ is the set of elements of degree zero in the localized ring $T^{-1}(S)$ where $T$ is the multplicative subset of all homogeneous elements of $S$ which are not contained in $\frak{p}$.

The function $s$ have the following conditions:

1. $s(p) \in S_{(p)}$
2. For each $\frak{p} \in U$, there exists an open subset $V \subset U$, and homogeneous elements $a,f$ in $S$ of the same degree, such that for all $\frak{q}$ $\in V$, $s(q) = \frac{a}{f}$ where $f \notin \frak{q}$. In other words, the function do not blow up locally for any $\frak{p} \in U$.

So now I want to see what $\mathcal{O}_x(n) = S(n)^{\sim}$ allows our functions $s$ to have poles of degree $n$.

In the original description of the structure sheaf it seems that poles were locally avoided by requiring that $f \notin \frak{q}$ for all $\frak{q}$ in near $\frak{p}$.

First of all, let us look at $S(n)_{(p)}$. In $S_{(p)}$ our elements where fractions, $\frac{s}{a}$, of homogeneous elements of the same degree.

Are the elements of $S(n)_{(p)}$ fractions of homogeneous elements which differ by $n$-degrees?

Furthermore condition $(2)$ above avoids poles by demanding that the denominator of our fractions are not contained in any prime ideal. However, it seems like this demand would still be in place for $S(n)^{\sim}$.

Why does $S(n)^{\sim}$ allow poles of degree $n$ but $S^{\sim}$ does not?

Comment: It's easy for me to get confused about this but I think one needs to take a step back: if your goal is to get poles then you don't need any new sheaves. $x_0/x_1$ has a pole of order $1$ at $(1:0)$. Taking powers I can get a pole of order $n$. This is even a regular function, using your definition, on $D(x_1)$. So the condition on denominators does not really prevent me from writing down functions with poles.

Comment: Can be useful this my answer? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596790/relation-between-stalks-of-twisted-sheaf-and-structure-sheaf/1656744#1656744